# Please undelete 'Unpaired word in one language but paired in another?' ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Please advise how to improve my question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11743/unpaired-word-in-one-language-but-paired-in-another.
 Please beware that I am requesting its undeletion on behalf of another user:

> [[Source:]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27563/what-do-you-call-words-that-look-like-a-negation-but-are-not?noredirect=1#comment568844_27563) 
>   @LePressentiment, I've seen many threads with -1 votes... so it couldn't be automatically deleted just because of that. Btw, I couldn't even see the link.. how to request for its undeletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was deleted by Community, i.e. by the system. This is because your answer fits various criteria:

- Score <= 0
- Closed more than 9 days before (yours was closed on 17, and deleted on 27)
- No activity (e.g. no edits) for 9 days, same rule as above.
- No answers with positive score.

And so on.

Anyway, I undeleted the question.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, may I please ask whether you can please undelete the others here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5306? Many of them contain helpful priceless comments that ought to be read.

Comment: @LePressentiment I don't think that's the right course of action. If I undelete all of your deleted questions, others might ask the same just because I said yes to you. You should pick each question at a time, see what's wrong with it, open a meta question, suggest changes and see if people agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

The best technique for avoiding the need to request undeletion is to avoid having questions closed. One of the best techniques for avoiding question-closure is to write questions that resist closing. The question in question is still unclear. If an exchange in the comments leads you to a deeper understanding of what leads to unclarity, the question itself has to be edited, possibly radically, to become clear.

[EDIT]Alenanno's comment points to the problem that fixing your question can make the helpful answers and comments contextually incomprehensible and subject to deletion or downvoting as "not an answer". My opinion is that all revisions of substance to a question should be carried out in a manner that preserves the original, such as putting an "Edit" tag in the text. Given the structure of SE, that I think is the only way to preserve the value of a good answer to a bad but improvable question.

Comment: I agree. Also, if the question has already been answered, you should not change the question radically, but post a new one based on it. If no-one answered yet, then I guess there's no problem.